# Gunicorn will not bind to my application

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I have made a django web app using the default localhost, however I am trying to set it up on a server so that I can configure a postgre database and continue on without having to redo the database later on.

I am hosting the site though a digital ocean ubuntu 14 droplet.  When I created the droplet I selected that it already come preconfigured for django.  It uses nginx and gunicorn to host the site.

When I first created the instance of the server, a basic django app was configured to work on the given IP. And it did.

I tried cloning my project into the same directory as that project assuming it would live on the python path ('/home/project') and configured the nginx to serve up 127.0.0.1:8000 per some of the documentation I found.

I believe the issue lies in when I try to bind gunicorn.  I get the following error with this input.

> gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8000 GenericRestaurantSystem/wsgi.py:application

```
ImportError: Failed to find application, did you mean 'program/wsgi:application'?
```

I am not 100% sure, but it seems as though gunicorn is not serving up anything (or not even on) at this point.

Any suggestions as to binding this application successfully?

Comment: not exactly related but if someone is looking for the updated article on this, found 1 mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62058404/aws-eb-unresolved-resource-dependencies/62270480#62270480

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Well that's not how you refer to the WSGI file with gunicorn. See [the docs](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/19.1.1/run.html#commands):

> The module name can be a full dotted path. The variable name refers to a WSGI callable that should be found in the specified module.

So if your wsgi.py file is in GenericRestaurantSystem/wsgi.py, your command should be

```
gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8000 GenericRestaurantSystem.wsgi:application
```

Comment: I don't understand how that command works. What is gunicorn doing when it encounters `GenericRestaurantSystem.wsgi:application`?

Comment: In other words: use project.wsgi (python import style) instead of project/wsgi (path style). I write this with regard to such poor people as I am, which could think that the name 'GenericRestaurantSystem' means some class inside.

Answer (score 6):

I guess it should be

```
gunicorn GenericRestaurantSystem.wsgi:application
```

Answer (score 1):

for me this work like charm :)

```
cd ~/myproject
gunicorn —bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and got it to work with this:

```
gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8000 wsgi:application
```

I put the `wsgi.py` file at the same level as `manage.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Create file in root you_django_name_project "main.py":

```
from you_django_name_project.wsgi import application
app = application
```

And run:

```
gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8000 main:app
```